# How to read one Numpy Array and get the value from another Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, indexing

I am new to Numpy / python so any help is much appreciated.
I have 2 arrays for each row in `X`. I have to get the value from `X2` and append it to a new array depending on if the `X` array value is `0` or `1`.

Steps:

1. See how many `0` or `1` in a row in `X`
2. Get value from the index in `X2`
3. For every `0` in `X`, add the value from `X2` into `arr0`
4. For every `1` value in `X`, add the value from `X2` into `arr1`
5. Iterate over all rows in `X`

So far, I have this and I am not sure where to go next:

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0,1,1,1,1],
             [0,1,1,1,0]])

X2 = np.array([[0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5],
              [0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.3]])

index =[]
arr0 =[]
arr1=[]

for i in X:
    getindex = np.take(probs, i) # get the value from index
    index.append(getindex)
```

Comment: You can almost do this in one line.  `arr0 = X2[X==0]` / `arr1 = X2[X==1]`  That says "copy to arr0 all elements of X2 where X is 0".

Comment: Something like `X2[np.where(X==1)]` ?

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you  but I now need to ensure I do this per row and not for the whole array at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the Numpy module `take_along_axis` [link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html)

```
X = np.array([[0,1,1,1,1],
          [0,1,1,1,0]])

X2 = np.array([[0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5],
          [0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.3]])

extrac_val=np.take_along_axis(X2, X[:], axis=1)
```

output

```
[[0.2 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]
 [0.3 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.3]]
```

Comment: thanks for this but how can I iterate to only get the Zero values so oy output is : [[0.2]
 [0.3 0.3]]

Comment: If my post answer your previous question, please kindly accept it as answer. and you can post another threas for this new particular question. just provide me the link